# Implementing a different background for each card

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I created a JSON file from which I create cards with different data using props in Reat.js. My issue it that I have created a custom CSS that give the card a background (covering the card content) and the on hover the background is disappearing and the content is shown. Everything works but I want to have a different background for each card, so I added in the JSON a bgImg: "imgagePath" and set a props.bgImg for the card, like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Project1",
    bgImg: "filePath",
    img: "filePath",
    description:
      "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velmollitia maiores error minus, incidunt sit non placeat ipsa, veniam,nam voluptatibus? Eius a dolores minima vitae recusandae provident quos inventore!",
    projectLink: "link",
  },
```

my CSS for the background is:

```css
#projectCard {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  width: 380px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#projectCard::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("filePath");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1.6s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#projectCard:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

while the jsx file is as follows:

```
import React from "react";

function ProjectCard(props) {
  return (
    <div id="projectCard">
      <div className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div id="imgContainer">
          <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} className="img" />
        </div>
        <h3 className="name projectName text-center">{props.name}</h3>
        <h5 className="details projectDetails">{props.details}</h5>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a
            href={props.projectLink}
            className="projectButton text-decoration-none fs-1 text-primary bg-warning rounded-pill text-center px-2"
          >
            Details
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProjectCard;
```

and then I have the other jsx file like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ProjectCard from "./ProjectCard";
import projects from "../projects";

function createProjectCard(project) {
  return (
    <ProjectCard
      key={project.id}
      bgImg={project.bgImg}
      img={project.img}
      name={project.name}
      details={project.description}
      projectLink={project.projectLink}
    />
  );
}

function Projects() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id="projects" className="sectionTitle d-none d-xl-block">
        PROJECTS
      </h1>
      <h1
        id="projects"
        className="sectionTitleMedium d-none d-md-block d-xl-none"
      >
        PROJECTS
      </h1>
      <h1 id="projects" className="sectionTitleSmall d-block d-md-none">
        PROJECTS
      </h1>
      <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-xl-row justify-content-around align-items-center mb-5">
        {projects.map(createProjectCard)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

So basically, I am mapping each object so that it creates a card with with different images, descriptions, titles...

I thought of implementing CSS directly into the JSX but was unsuccessful. I thought maybe using the UseState() but not sure if that would work.

Comment: Your code seems working fine. What exactly is your question and what is it that you need help with?

Comment: At the moment my cards all have the same bg, because of the css code. I'm having trouble how I could implement a feature where each card has a different bg rather than all having the same.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue - the code now generates each card with a className="project + the respective id.

```html
import React from "react";

function ProjectCard(props) {
  const className = `project project${props.id}`;

  return (
    <div id="projectCard" className={`${className}`}>
      <div className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div id="imgContainer">
          <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} className="img" />
        </div>
        <h3 className="name projectName text-center">{props.name}</h3>
        <h5 className="details projectDetails">{props.details}</h5>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a
            href={props.projectLink}
            className="projectButton text-decoration-none fs-1 text-primary bg-warning rounded-pill text-center px-2"
          >
            Details
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProjectCard;
```

This way I can then apply the css (which uses ::before) for each card by using the .projectID. The CSS is tedious but it's the best solution I could think of. Now in the css if the object has id: 1, I can simply apply css by doing .project1 {/*CSS Code*/}.

```css
.project1 {
/*CSS Code*/
}
```

Open to better suggestions.